# Combobox 'OnSelectedIndexChanged' not firing for certain values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp combo box inside  update panel with autopost back set to true.
On page Load I fill combo box as

```
public DataTable getProductDetails()
{
    MasterAllocationDB dataHandler = new MasterAllocationDB();
    DataTable dataBoxType = null;
    DataRow row = null;
    try
    {
        dataBoxType = dataHandler.GetBoxType();
        if (dataBoxType != null && dataBoxType.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            row = dataBoxType.NewRow();
            row["Product"] = "--Select--";
            dataBoxType.Rows.InsertAt(row,0);
            row =  dataBoxType.NewRow();
            row["Product"] = "Other";
            dataBoxType.Rows.InsertAt(row, dataBoxType.Rows.Count);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHandler.LogMessageToFile(ex, LogMode.Fatal);
    }

    return dataBoxType;
}
```

Also I have a `onselectedindexchanged` event binded

```
protected void productComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string json = null;
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row = null;
            var s = this.productComboBox.SelectedValue;
            try
            {
                int totalNoOfItems = this.productComboBox.Items.Count;

                // Make sure that Index are between "select a value" and "Other"
                if (this.productComboBox.SelectedIndex > 0 && this.productComboBox.SelectedIndex < totalNoOfItems - 1) 
                {
                    //code here
                }
                json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rows);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogHandler.LogMessageToFile(ex, LogMode.Fatal);
            }

        }
```

As you can see I have added 2 extra rows besides the rows fetched from DB.The data rows are binding properly as I can see the same in outputed combo box values

After running I noticed that whenever I select "other" the text inside combo box gets changed
to "--select--" and control never reaches `onselectedindexchanged`

It works finely for all the other cases. What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you show the code for 'onselectindexchanged'?

Comment: @sr28 added it in question

Answer (score 0):

Ok I sorted it out.
The problem is that I have only set text for the combo box not  value for options.

Changed the code as

```
  row["Product"] = "--Select--";
  row["ProductID"] = "0";

  row["Product"] = "Other";
  row["ProductID"] = "10";
```

ProductId gives the value for combobox.
Happy coding